# Agregar marca de agua en Android utilizando Glide

Tags: android, android-studio, bitmap, android-glide

Tengo el código para agregar una imagen en un imageview:

```
        try {
        Glide.with(imagen.getContext())
                .load(item.getIdImagen())
                //.transform(new GestorImagenes(context, 90f))
                .into(imagen);
    } catch(Exception e) {
    }
```

Tambien tengo el codigo que agregaria la marca de agua:

```
public Bitmap applyWaterMarkEffect(Bitmap src, String watermark, int x, int y, int color, int alpha, int size, boolean underline) {
    int w = src.getWidth();
    int h = src.getHeight();
    Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, src.getConfig());

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);
    canvas.drawBitmap(src, 0, 0, null);

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(color);
    paint.setAlpha(alpha);
    paint.setTextSize(size);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setUnderlineText(underline);
    canvas.drawText(watermark, x, y, paint);

    return result;
}
```

El problema es que no se como combinarlos para mostrar todo junto. ¿Debería tomar la imagen(bitmap) para pasarla como parametro? En ese caso ¿Como la tomo?

Gracias!

Comment: Me parece muy interesante tu pregunta, en el caso de Glide como Picasso solo acepta archivo de recursos, assets, files y content providers. Pero debe existir una forma de cargar el Bitmap, aúnque lo que realiza Glide es precisamente convertir a Bitmap el recurso.

Comment: Lei en el GitHub de Glide que a través del método ".override(int, int)" puedo hacer lo que pido, pero no había ni explicacion ni nada mas al respecto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo resolví con el seiguiente código:

```
Glide  
.with(context)
.load(someUrl)
.bitmapTransform(new WatermarkTransformation(context))
.into(imageView);
```

Dentro de el método "WatermarkTransformation" pongo el comportamiento deseado.